# UIImage padding for portrait images

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, landscape-portrait

I have a `UIViewController` with `UIImage` of fixed lanscape size (w:280, h:180).

in it I'm display the image extracted from `[p_info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

for portrait images i wish to add padding so the frame size doesn't change and the picture doesn't loose it's ratios,

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just set your UIImageView's content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` or `UIViewContentModeCenter`, depending on the size of the image